# How to apply entire string as an attribute/prop to Lit web component?

Tags: web-component, template-literals, lit, lit-html

I have a basic Text Lit web component with a red color for styling as such

```js
import { LitElement, html } from "lit";
import { customElement } from "lit/decorators.js";

@customElement("bb-text")
export class Text extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html` <p style="color: red;"><slot></slot></p> `;
  }
}
```

I would like to pass the entire style attribute as a string like so

```js
import { LitElement, html } from "lit";
import { customElement } from "lit/decorators.js";

function getStyle() {
  return 'style="color: red;"';
}

@customElement("bb-text")
export class Text extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html` <p ${getStyle()}><slot></slot></p> `;
  }
}
```

What I have tried

1. unsafeHTML: doesn't even render component

   ```js
   return html` <p ${unsafeHTML(getStyle())}><slot></slot></p> `;
   ```
2. custom directive: does nothing

   ```js
   import { LitElement, html } from "lit";
   import { customElement } from "lit/decorators.js";
   import { Directive, directive } from "lit/directive.js";

   class StyleDirective extends Directive {
     render() {
       return 'style="color: red;"';
     }
   }
   const getStyle = directive(StyleDirective);

   @customElement("bb-text")
   export class Text extends LitElement {
     render() {
       return html` <p ${getStyle()}><slot></slot></p> `;
     }
   }
   ```

Lit's documentation on [Element Expressions](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#element-expressions) implies that it should be possible

```js
html`<div ${myDirective()}></div>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [static expressions](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#static-expressions) for that.

```js
import { html, unsafeStatic } from "lit/static-html.js";
import { LitElement } from "lit";
import { customElement } from "lit/decorators.js";

function getStyle() {
  return 'style="color: red;"';
}

@customElement("bb-text")
export class Text extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html` <p ${unsafeStatic(getStyle())}><slot></slot></p> `;
  }
}
```